# Retrieve real-time SQL requests between Oracle and Tomcat server

Tags: sql, oracle, tomcat, monitoring, loadrunner

I'm running a LoadRunner script which generates **"Missing IN or OUT parameter at Index:: 1"**. I think this may come from a sql statement. So I want to get the SQL requests in real-time between my Tomcat server and the Oracle database. I tried to seach on Oracle Enterprise Manager, but didn't get anything useful (I'm not familliar with this tool). So I wonder if there are something that can display the SQL requests(statements) and in what time they have been executed. I don't care about the performence, things like how much time they take, how many percentage of CPU they use, ect..

Is there some tools can do this job? Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks at your tomcat log and your database transaction logs if you are looking for a time context for when a particular event occurs.   If you are looking at frequency, performance, top talkers on your DB then you want to invoke whatever profiler you have your your particular database solution.